# Skip a character from character class

Tags: regex, grep

I am using following grep code to search single arabic characters only in Adobe Indesign:

`\b[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}\x{0750}-\x{077F}]{1}\b`
All is working fine except that I want to skip just one character from the above range i.e **\x{0640}**
I am unable to do that in the above code.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```
\b[\x{0600}-\x{063F}\x{0641}-\x{06FF}\x{0750}-\x{077F}]\b
```

`\x{0640}` is excluded.

Comment: It worked, however, what if I would like to skip a range of characters out of the accepted range another possibility would be skip more than one characters of different range.  For example accept a to z except e, h, j

Comment: @Shahid: You can do `[a-dfgik-z]` or, using negative lookahead: `(?:(?![ehj])[a-z])+`

Comment: Thank you. It helped.